# How to create gravity forms loading screen

Tags: jquery, ajax, gravityforms

I'm currently using the gform_ajax_spinner_url to replace the spinner on the gravity forms ajax submission. However, I'm wondering if it's possible to tie in the ajaxStart / ajaxStop to a gravity form that will show/hide an element that is acting as a loading screen. (I've attached a reference image below). Again, I am aware and currently using the hook to replace the default ajax spinner, I just need to know if it's possible to fire a script as soon as the button is pressed to enable my custom loading screen.

[image: Loading Screen Element]

Comment: What happened when you tried it?   If "gravityforms" is using jquery's .ajax (or overloads) then they should also fire.

Comment: @freedomn-m yeah, I did try that and the script simply doesn't fire. Here's the script I'm trying to run.jQuery(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    jQuery("#ajaxLoading").fadeIn("slow");
   });

   jQuery(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    jQuery("#ajaxLoading").fadeOut("slow");
    // jQuery("#st-tree-container").show();
   });